Vue3 Tree with TreeItem component, How to get the parent component using composition API
All the children always equal 100%. This means when I increase one child, all the other children are reduced.
I want to change the slider value manually and by programming
I am using typescript in a composition <script setup lang="ts">
In the TreeItem I have a slider that changes. I can emit this change to the TreeRow.
I pass the data and the parent data down the tree using props.
const props = defineProps<{
    "parent": wasm.JAcct,
    'acct': wasm.JAcct,
    "level": number
}>()

where JAcct is defined as in RUST as:
#[wasm_bindgen(getter_with_clone)]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct JAcct {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub key: BKey,
    pub value: f64,
    pub original: i64,
    pub percent: f64,
    pub locked: bool,
    pub children: Vec<JAcct>,
}

This is how I create the tree
<div  v-show="show" v-for="chld in acct.children" :key="chld.id">
    <TreeRow :acct="chld" :parent="acct" :level="level+1" />
</div>

But this does not pass the parent component, just the parent data.
Using options API I would use :parent="this" or this.$parent 
How do I access the parent component in composition API?
That would allow me to change the slider value using typescript or manual.
